# Switch/case statement- String(first char specific and the rest don't care)

Tags: java

In a `switch(string)` can i make a case to start with a specific char f.e `case('N')`  and then followed by other characters that i don't care about them? f.e NOC

```
case("N**"):
case("1**"):
case("0**"):
    BalancedTrenary term = new BalancedTrenary(parts[i]);
```

Comment: Show us your code ?

Comment: `switch (myString.charAt(0)) { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `charAt` and use char in the cases

```
String str = "NOC";
switch (str.charAt(0)) {
    case 'N':
         // do something here
         break;
}
```

Be aware that the `case` is case sensitive. To make it ignored case use another case with `n`

```
switch (str.charAt(0)) {
    case 'N':
    case 'n':
        // do something here
        break;
}
```